# issue while calculating average price in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, average

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace average_stock_calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double  a, b, sum, average;

            Console.WriteLine("First purchase price:");
            a = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine("Second purchase price:");
            b = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

            //Processing
            sum = a + b;
            average = sum/2;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Average buying price={0}", average);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I input the first buying price, I want to enter the amount in decimal like `10.20`, while for the second buying price `20.20`, then I should compute the average price and print it, but when I run the code it throws an error.

Can you help me?

Comment: What error did you get? Anyway, hints, you should use `Convert.ToDouble()` or `Convert.ToDecimal()` instead of `Convert.ToInt64()`.

Comment: *it throws an error.* - please never, ever again seek help from a fellow programming professional and say "i got an error" without mentioning the exact error message. The error message is the single most useful piece of info you can give us. If you doubt this, please work a helpdesk for a week; it will massively increase your desire to report bugs like a developer does rather than a regular user does :D

Comment: If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with money is always a good practice to use `decimal`, you could use `float` or `double`, but you could end with a rounding issue.

The problem in your code is that you were trying to use an `int` variable to store a `decimal` entry, so a conversion exception was being thrown.

Your code should looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal a, b, sum, average;

    Console.WriteLine("First purchase price:");
    a = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Second purchase price:");
    b = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    //Processing
    sum = a + b;
    average = sum / 2m;

    Console.WriteLine("Average buying price={0}", average);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to parse string, that contains floating-point value into integer one.

Possible solutions:

```cs
var x = Convert.ToDouble(input);
```

```cs
var x = Convert.ToDecimal(input);
```

```cs
var x = double.Parse(input);
```

```cs
var x = decimal.Parse(input);
```

```cs
if (double.TryParse(input, out var x)) 
{
    // do smth with x 
}
```

```cs
if (decimal.TryParse(input, out var x)) 
{
    // do smth with x 
}
```